# Javascript - If statements check both expression and definition declaration? This is confusing

Tags: javascript

```
var boolTrue = true;
var randomObject;

if (boolTrue)
// this will fire

if (randomObject)
// this will fire, because the object is defined

if (!objectNotDefined)
// this will fire, because there is no defined object named 'objectNotDefined'
```

Coming from a C++ and C# background, I am very familiar with the basic if(expression) syntax.  However, I think it is not very readable to have both expressions (true/false) and have object existence also being a expression.  Because now if I see a function like below, i don't know if the data coming in is an object (existence/undefined check) or a boolean.

```
function(data) {
   if (data)
      // is this checking if the object is true/false or if the object is in existence?
}
```

Is this just the way it is?  I mean, is there anyway to easily read this?  Also, where is this documented anywhere in the JS spec (curious)?

Comment: Your example is wrong.  `if (randomObject)` will NOT fire, it's `false`.  `if (!objectNotDefined)` will give an error `"objectNotDefined is not defined"`.

Comment: It's documented here: http://es5.github.com/#x9.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript everything is "true" (or "truthy" to be more precise using Javascript parlance) except `false`, `0`, `undefined`, `null`, `NaN` and empty string.

To avoid confusion use:

```
 if (data === true) // Is it really true?
```

and

```
if (typeof data === 'undefined') // Is the variable undefined?
```

Answer (score 1):

It checks whether it is *truthy*.

In JavaScript, everything is truthy except `false`, `0`, `""`, `undefined`, `null` and `NaN`.

So, `true` will pass, as well as *any* object (also empty objects/arrays/etc).

Note that your third comment is true if you mean "declared but not defined" - a variable that has never been *declared* throws a `ReferenceError` on access. A declared, non-defined variable (`var something;`) is `undefined` (so, not truthy) so it will indeed pass the condition if you negate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for (non-)existence separately:

```
if ( typeof variable == 'undefined' ) {
  // other code
}
```

However, the syntax you show is commonly used as a much shorter form and is sufficient in most usecases.

Answer (score 1):

The following values are equivalent to false in conditional statements:

```
false
null
undefined
The empty string ”
The number 0
The number NaN
```